# Wpf Prism Region Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I've been trying to get view-based navigation to work using Prism and regions. I tried going through the documentation on MSDN, but for some reason I can't get it to work, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. So this is what I got so far:

MainShellViewModel.cs

```
//Private Variables
private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

//Public Variables
public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

//Functions and Methods
public MainShellViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    //Region Manager
    _regionManager = regionManager;
    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    Initialize();
}

public void Initialize()
{
    //Startup View
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ViewMainFrame", typeof(Views.Dashboard));
}

public void Navigate(string uri)
{
    //Navigation
    if(uri != null)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ViewMainFrame", uri);
    }
}
```

Side note: One of the many tutorials I followed had me put in that Navigate method, do I need it? I am using the MainShellViewModel as the Main view that is injected on startup.

DashboardViewModel.cs: (Contains the error)

```
{
    //Private Variables
    private bool _canExercise = true;

    //Public Variables
    public bool CanExercise()
    {
        return _canExercise;
    }

    RelayCommand _exerciseSelCommand;
    public ICommand ExerciseSelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_exerciseSelCommand == null)
                _exerciseSelCommand = new RelayCommand(ExerciseSel, CanExercise);

            return _exerciseSelCommand;
        }
    }

    //Dashboard Functions and Methods
    IRegion _regionManager;

    private void ExerciseSel()
    {
        SoundPlayers.ButtonSound();
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(new Uri("ExerciseView", UriKind.Relative)); //This gives me the error, it says it can't be nullable?
    }
```

Here is where I register my containers/views, etc.

Bootstrapper.cs:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    #region Region Register Zone
    //register views here!
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.LoginView), "LoginView");
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.Dashboard), "Dashboard");
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.ExerciseView), "SettingsView"); 
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.ResultsView), "ResultsView");
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.UserCreationView), "UserCreationView");
    #endregion
}
```

So basically I just want to be able to get from the Dashboard (Which is my current startup view) to any other view that's registered in my containers on a click of a button.

MainShell.xaml:

```
<Window x:Name="Shell" 
    x:Class="Equinox.Views.MainShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="Equinox"
    FontFamily="Quicksand"
    Height="900" 
    Width="1500"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    Background="#EEF3F4"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    Icon="/Equinox;component/favicon.ico"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<!-- Main View Region -->

<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControlMain"
                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ViewMainFrame" 
                Focusable="False"/>
```

However, I keep getting errors when I try to make my region take another view. The way I was doing it was by using my DashboardViewModel, and creating another `IRegionManager` named `_regionManager`, and doing the RequestNavigation. I got no errors until I ran it and pressed the button that should link me to the next view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the dashboard VM code, i.e. where you are creating the IRegionManager and where you call its RequestNavigation() method? Also, can you provide details of the error message you are seeing? Just to double-check, you should be injecting IRegionManager into your dashboard VM (like you do with the main VM), and the IRegionManager must be registered as a *singleton* in your bootstrapper.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I just added it. xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you got the answer already, but I was running into the same thing today. The comment from Brian gave me the necessary hint.

I have the following code in the bootstrapper. This registers the two views to allow navigation to them:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>("ViewA");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewB>("ViewB");
    }
}
```

This gives a MainWindow, which registers ViewA and ViewB.
To allow for navigation to ViewB from a button on ViewA, the following needs to be done in ViewAViewModel:

```
public class ViewAViewModel: BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ViewAViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        ButtonCommand= new DelegateCommand(ButtonClicked);
    }        

    private void ButtonClicked()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewB");
    }
}
```

In the XAML form ViewA the last thing you need is of course the button itself:

```
<Button Content="Navigate" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Yea I got the answer, thanks tho man! That is the way I did it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out sampels 17, 18, and 19.  This should help get you going in the right direction:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Comment: Looking at the examples, and replicating them keeps giving me errors. I noticed they all have just one view and that is MainWindow. Well I have a Mainshelll, and in that shell is a view I injected. I'm trying to get it to display another view inside that shell when I press a button inside the view. I've been trying different variations but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the samples?  It has a shell that allows you to navigated multiple views in the region.  You can navigate between the views easily by clicking the buttons.  You're probably just missing the entire concept altogether.  It is actually very simple.

Comment: All you do is make sure your views are registered for navigation, and then call IRegionManager.RequestNaviagte and that's it.

Comment: Yea, I most likely am missing it, I am relatively new lol. I am still trying to grasp my head around it. This question, and this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164109/using-prism-to-inject-and-navigate-views is what I got so far. So when you say register, I thought that's what the containers are for in my bootstrapper?

Comment: Look at the samples I provided and run them